# Text doing weird "wrap around" movement caused by menu above it

Tags: html, css

I can't explain it too well, but for some reason when you hover over the menu links in the header, the text below it - in a whole other div - starts moving as if it needs to wrap around the menu. There is also a large dent in the text too right where the menu is.

The strange thing is, this only happens if <!DOCTYPE html> is added at the start of the HTML file. Without it, it behaves as it should.

Obligatory JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c1zaotzg

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

And for some reason, obligatory code.

Answer (score 2):

Give Your **#headercont** **overflow:hidden**

```
#headercont {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1000px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This did it. Not sure if i can mark as best answer yet though

Comment: Its happening because of line-height given to #header, #footer i.e 100px...  otherway to solve this is giving max-height: 101px to your #menu..

Answer (score 1):

Your `line-height` inside the element `#header` actually does the weird thing. And why not wrap the word **WEBSITE** too just like what you did in your menu. See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c1zaotzg/20/)

Answer (score 0):

otherway to solve this is `giving max-height: 101px` to your **#menu**..

Comment: please update your existing answer below. Don't make another one.